# 301 complex redirection via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Hi Guys i'm currently in the middle of a migration, and need the clients traffic to be sent as a fail save the new url's.

The old domain would have something like olddomain.com/abcd/1234 and i need to redirect that to newdomain.com/?paramenter1=1234&parameter2=ABCD.

This is probably something easy to do and i'm guessing this can be done via a .htaccess request so we can make sure there's no left over traffic. I'm not a developer but i'm a techie and need to advise the client's tech on placing this one since this is actually my idea to help them out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `.htaccess` rule will redirect http://olddomain.com/abcd/1234 to http://newdomain.com/?paramenter1=abcd&parameter2=1234.

Notice that the two captured groups (defined by parantheses) from the regular expression are numbered from 1 and up. So the first captured group will be accessible in the redirect url as **$1** while the second group will be accessible as **$2**. Please adjust accordingly to your requirements.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ http://newdomain.com/?parameter1=$1&parameter2=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No problemo! Please mark my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: i've just realize the old domain is actually http://olddomain.com**bold**/z**bold**/abcd/1234i forgot the /z would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes it would. Change `^(.+)/(.+)$` to `^z/(.+)/(.+)$`